# Window handle is invalid

Tags: c#, xna, windows, windows-forms, fna

I'm trying to implement an input listener for [FNA](https://fna-xna.github.io/) (modern version of XNA). Since FNA does not supply any sort of way to listen to native input this has to be done through the windows API and native calls. This is how I set this up:

```
public KeyboardListener(GameWindow window) {
    var procedurePointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate<WindowProcedure>(Procedure);
    procedure = new IntPtr(SetWindowLongPtr(window.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, procedurePointer.ToInt64()));
    if (procedure == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var error = GetLastError();
        throw error switch
        {
            ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE => new InvalidOperationException("Invalid window handle"),
            _ => new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown error message '0x{error:X4}'")
        };
    }
}

// https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptra#parameters
private const int GWL_WNDPROC = -4;

// https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlonga
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern int SetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern uint GetLastError();
```

I construct the keyboard listener during the `Initialize` method of `Game`:

```
class MyGame : Game {
    protected override void Initialize() {
        new KeyboardListener(Window);
    }
}
```

This is the method call that reports the error: `SetWindowLongPtr(window.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, procedurePointer.ToInt64())` and it throws `"Invalid window handle"`. It's worth noting that the example code I saw converted the pointers to `Int32` instead of `Int64`, but I am on a 64 bit machine so the pointers can not fit in 32 bits.

---

#### What I've tried & figured out so far...

- Debugging tells me that both `window.Handle` and `procedurePointer`
  are non-null and at least point to *something*.
- I have tried to initialize it earlier or later, but that doesn't seem to make a
  difference.
- Other native methods such as `SDL2.SDL.SDL_MinimizeWindow(Window.Handle)` work perfectly fine and don't complain about the window handle.

Answer (score 1):

So after like 5 hours of debugging of course I solve it 3 minutes after I write up this answer (as always Stack Exchange is the best rubber duck).

The clue is that `SDL2.SDL.SDL_MinimizeWindow(Window.Handle)` and all other SDL calls work perfectly fine. Turns out FNA is slightly different from XNA in that `Window.Handle` points to an `SDL` window, not a Win32 window.

The fix for this is easy, fortunately:

```
// This is required, otherwise this procedure will be garbage collected. Note that this field must be static.
private static WindowPointer nonGcProcedure;

public KeyboardListener(GameWindow window) {
    nonGcProcedure ??= Procedure;

    // Convert the SDL handle to a win handle
    var info = new SDL.SDL_SysWMinfo();
    SDL.SDL_VERSION(out info.version); // This *might* not be required
    if (SDL.SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window.Handle, ref info) == SDL.SDL_bool.SDL_FALSE)
        throw new InvalidOperationException();

    var winPointer = info.info.win.window;
    var procedurePointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(nonGcProcedure);
    procedure = new IntPtr(SetWindowLongPtr(winPointer, GWL_WNDPROC, procedurePointer.ToInt64()));
    if (procedure == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var error = GetLastError();
        throw error switch
        {
            ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE => new InvalidOperationException("Invalid window handle"),
            _ => new InvalidOperationException($"Unknown error message '0x{error:X4}'")
        };
    }
}
```